# perform a set of functions after jQuery validate()

Tags: jquery, validation

i'm using jQuery validate() plugin to validate a form. it does the validation but how do i perform a set of function if there are no errors?

i've tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('php/contact.php', { 
            name: $('form #name').val(), 
            email: $('form #email').val(), 
            comments: $('form #comments').val() },
            function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    alert('thank you');
                }
                else {
                    alert('error');
                }
        }, 'json');
        form.submit();
    }
    });
});
```

The form validates but i'm not getting data.success as true from php now. any ideas?

Comment: if its not a typo, you're missing a closing parantheses behind `$('form')`

Comment: thanks for that. the validation works now but i'm not getting the data.success = true from php now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`submitHandler` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for this:

```
$("form").validate({
  //rules, etc..
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //do something, it was valid
  }
});
```

The opposite handler for this is the `invalidHandler` which executes when the submitted form was not valid.

Comment: @pixeltocode: Which part?  You're making an ajax request then submitting the form (probably cancelling that request), what isn't working?

Comment: when i put the $.post within a .click() function, the form submits. when add the validate(), it validates the form and submits it. when i use the submitHandler, nothing happens.

Comment: @pixeltocode - Did you try putting just an alert in? (Also in the `invalidHandler` since your form may be invalid) Currently you're not adding any validation rules...so why are you even using the validation plugin?

Comment: @pixeltocode - You're saying the form is not submitting at all?

Comment: if it submits i data.success will be true and the alert should work, right?

Comment: @pixeltocode - You're firing off an ajax request, then submitting the form which abandons the AJAX call, if you want it to only run when `data.success` is there, you should move `form.submit();` into that if statement, but you're being *very* unclear about what doesn't work...

Comment: @Nick Craver, as you pointed out, the problem was form.submit(). removed it and now the ajax call is made only if the required field are filled. cool...thanks! +1 for you